# Java JLabel Onto Custom Class

Tags: java, class, jlabel

I'm programming a spaceship style game similar to space invaders to test my programming (I'm relatively new). I made a class for my ship with different methods to move the ship, but there's no image attached to the class. Is it possible to make the class (Ship) be represented by a JLabel so if I did ship.moveLeft() an image would move left? Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.io.*; 
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class Ship {
    private int shipX;
    private int shipY;
    public int i;

    public Ship() {
        shipX = 475;
        shipY = 425;
        i = 0;
    }

    public void moveShip(int key) {
        if (key == 97) { //A
            while (i == 0) {
                sleep(50);
                shipX -= 5;
            }
        } else if (key == 100) { //D
            while (i == 0) {
                sleep(50);
                shipX += 5;
            }
        }
    }

public int getX() {
    return shipX;
}

public int getY() {
    return shipY;
}

public void isMoving(boolean moving) {
    if (!moving) {
        i = 1;
    }
}

public void sleep(int x) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(x);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
} 
}
```

so in my main class I did

```
Ship player = new Ship();
```

would it be possible to make the player both a Ship and a JLabel?

Comment: Usually you seperate your Ship (Model) from the image/gui (View). I would recommend you to read something about Model-View-Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to the question of whether you can have the ship as a JLabel, and assuming that you know what you are doing thereon, you can make a class for the ship that extends the JLabel class:

```
public class ship extends JLabel {...}
```

and you automatically have everything a JLabel has, plus whatever you add.

Comment: never knew about that, I should really read up on java logic and what not. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use `Key Bindings`.

See [Motion Using the Keyboared](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information about the two approaches including working examples of both approaches. The examples use a JLabel to display the image.

```
if (key == 97)
```

Also, don't use "magic numbers". Nobody know what "97" means. Use the fields defined in the API:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_???)
```

Comment: I've used the keyevent but for some reason on my laptop it didn't register (the arrow keys didn't). Possibly because I'm running ubuntu??